# bash issue with variables containing a single quote

Tags: php, bash, quote

I'm trying to run a command at the command prompt and if one of the values includes a single quote it doesn't run correctly.

The command I'm using is :

`lxc-attach -n test -- bash -c 'echo 'abcd1234' > /home/rocket/test.log'`

This will complete without issue and abcd1234 is written to the test.log correctly.

However if I run the command with abcd'1234 then the command doesn't update the log file.

`lxc-attach -n test -- bash -c 'echo 'abcd'1234' > /home/rocket/test.log'`

I've tried escaping the ' with \ but that hasn't helped.

Could someone advise how to get this to run.

Thanks

**UPDATE** I'm actually running this from a PHP page and using SSH to update the server. The actual command being run is:

```
$update = "echo $password | sudo -S lxc-attach -n $server -- bash -c 'echo \"$value\" >> /home/rocket/test.log'";
$ssh->exec( $update );
```

Where $value may contain a single quote.

Comment: Please be very explicit about which quote symbols you want to be interpreted as syntax (consumed by the shell as instructions on how to interpret surrounding content) and which quotes you mean to be literal (actual data, to be emitted by echo as output). It's not obvious from the question what you think correct output _should_ be.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to get this working.

```
$value = str_replace( "'", "'\''", $value );

$update = "echo $password | sudo -S lxc-attach -n $server -- bash -c 'echo \"$value\" >> /home/rocket/test.log'";
```

$value is now shown correctly in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Since $password is completely arbitrary, you'll want to use [`escapeshellarg`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) on it to sanitize it.

Since this is a complex command, you'll need to use it multiple times, it's the only way to be sure the inputs are completely sanitized. I've gone ahead and fixed the escaping on `$value` and `$server` too:

```php
$bash_command = 'echo ' . escapeshellarg($value) . ' >> /home/rocket/test.log';
$update = 'echo ' . escapeshellarg($password) .
    ' | sudo -S lxc-attach -n ' . escapeshellarg($server) .
    ' -- bash -c ' . escapeshellarg($bash_command);

$ssh->exec( $update );
```

Cleaner solution using `sprintf`:

```php
$bash_command = sprintf('echo %s >> /home/rocket/test.log',
    escapeshellarg($value),
);
$update = sprintf('echo %s | sudo -S lxc-attach -n %s -- bash -c %s',
    escapeshellarg($password),
    escapeshellarg($server),
    escapeshellarg($bash_command),
);
$ssh->exec( $update );
```

Doing this results in the sanitized string,

```bash
echo 'abcd'\''1234' | sudo -S lxc-attach -n 'example.com' -- bash -c 'echo '\''hello world'\'' >> /home/rocket/test.log'
```

And yes, that absolute mess *IS* how you need to phrase literal single quotes when used alongside single-quoted strings in shell. Hey look, even SO's markdown parser has trouble with it. O__o Luckily you don't need to care about manually doing it if you use `escapeshellarg` in my code above.

I'm always paranoid about user-generated input ever since the [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/) incident.

Answer (score -1):

What I would do:

```
lxc-attach -n test -- bash -c 'echo "abcd'1234" > /home/rocket/test.log'
```

or:

```
lxc-attach -n test -- bash<<'EOF'
echo "abcd'1234" > /home/rocket/test.log
EOF
```

Comment: The single quote partway through the first branch of this answer is syntactic, not literal.

Comment: Thanks. I'd not included in my original post that the command was being run via PHP. I've updated the post to reflect this. Is there any way to do this ? Thanks